# How to post data for two properties afrer choosing only one option from radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have radio buttons, where you have two options for payment - 30 days and 60 days. After choosing one option, I am making a post request and sending the chosen value to database.
What I want to do is, that after clicking one option, I want to send value for two properties at the same time.

Now it only sends the value for `payment_term_days:60` or `payment_term_days:30`.
What I would like to have after choosing one option that it would be:
`payment_term_days:60` and `payment_term_pct: 1,5`

I am using vue.js. How would it be possible, could I pass two parameters in v-model?

Thank you a lot.

**HTML**

```
<form class="radioForm" role="form">
  <input 
         v-model = "newContract.payment_term_days"
         type="radio"
         id="60" 
         name="payment" 
         value="60"
         >
  <label for="60">60 Days, 1,5 % Commission</label><br>

  <input 
         v-model = "newContract.payment_term_days"
         type="radio" 
         id="30" 
         name="payment" 
         value="30"
         >
  <label for="30">30 Days, 4,0 % Commission.</label><br>
</form>
```

**Vue.js**

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  delimiters: ["[[", "]]"],
  data() {
    return {
      newContract: {
        payment_term_days: "",
        payment_term_pct: null
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    sendAGB(newContract) {
      let fd = new FormData();
      fd.append("payment_term_days", newContract.payment_term_days);
      fd.append("payment_term_pct", newContract.payment_term_pct);

      let req = new Request(agbPath, {
        body: fd,
        headers,
        method: "POST"           
      });  

      fetch(req) 
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
        alert("You have agreed terms and conditions")
        this.newContract = {
          payment_term_days: "",
          payment_term_pct: 0,
        }
      })
        .catch((error) => console.log("error", error));
    },
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a computed.  Remove the `data` variable `payment_term_pct` and use:

```js
data() {
  return {
    newContract: {
      payment_term_days: ""
    }
  }
},
computed: {
  payment_term_pct() {
    const daysToPct = {
      30: 4,
      60: 1.5
    }
    return daysToPct[this.newContract.payment_term_days];
  }
}
```

The method references to data should be:

```js
fd.append("payment_term_days", this.newContract.payment_term_days);
fd.append("payment_term_pct", this.payment_term_pct);
```

Comment: thank you. Unfortunately it is not working, I have two times payment_term_pct in request(even after deleting) and has no value in it.

Comment: You'll need to adjust your request a bit every time you used `payment_term_pct` since the computed is not in the same location as before.  Refer to it as `this.payment_term_pct` instead of `this.newContract.payment_term_pct`.